# Django boto3 error during collectstatic command

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to run a gitlab project on a local machine. I have a problem at the start of the command

```
manage.py collectstatic
```

**error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 199, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 124, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 354, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 260, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto3.py", line 532, in exists
    self.connection.meta.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=name)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 634, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 680, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model, context)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 712, in _emit_api_params
    params=api_params, model=operation_model, context=context)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 356, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 228, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 211, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/home/y700/Env/healthline/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py", line 219, in validate_bucket_name
    if VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) is None:
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I tried to update the boto3 version, but it didn't help.

**settings.py (part)**

```
....
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app', 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
....
```

else  I have settings for AWS server

```
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'app.storage_backends.PrivateMediaStorage'
AWS_PUBLIC_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static/'
```

Comment: The problem might be in `PrivateMediaStorage`.

Comment: @Alasdair Yes you are right, I have some issues with aws settings. Can I exclude the AWS settings to run a project on a local machine?

Comment: I don't know your project so I can't tell whether you can run it locally. Note that if you are running a project locally with `python manage.py runserver` then you shouldn't need to run `collectstatic`. Usually you only need `collectstatic` when you deploy.

Comment: @Alasdair ok, thank you